# Selecting serializer field in the DRF browsable API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For example my model and its serializer:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150)


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__' # to select these fields on the browsable API
```

So my aim is to be able to select serializer fields in the browsable API view without going into code (to modify fields variable in the serializer class).
I thought about adding a filterset class with a MultipleChoiceFilter field for serializer field names, so I can select the fields I want to display in the filter form.

```
class PersonFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    FIELD_CHOICES = (
        ('name', 'Name'),
        ('age', 'Age'),
        ('city', 'City'),
    )
    field = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(label='fields',
                                        choices=FIELD_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['field']
```

And my generic view class:

```
class PersonList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    filterset_class = PersonFilter
```

What I try to do is:

Selecting the fields from this json query:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "London",
},
```

[by using the filter on the browsable API :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct9zl.png)

obtaining this subset of fields:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "city": "London",
}
```

At this point I couldn't find out how to manipulate the serializer fields variable from my view by using filterset. I tried to create a dynamic field serializer class so I can get an additional 'fields' argument. And I used it in a fbv instead of cbv to be able to use the serializer as an instance, but with a fbv I cannot have a filter form in the browsable api.  Also I don't know if it's a good practice to do it or there's a simpler way.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to mimic a graphql architecture? If that's the case, I would use graphene, it works really nice with django https://www.fullstacklabs.co/blog/django-graphene-rest-graphql

Comment: i believe the better way is to filter inside of your `views.py`, not in serializer

Comment: Yes I agree, but I don't know how can I call the user selection from the choice filter of the filterset in my view class, and use it to select the serializer fields. @oruchkin